# Enable extra filter for Kendo date column

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, filtering

I've a Kendo grid with 4 columns and one of the columns is date type.

I want to display extra filter options for date type column. Below is my trail.

```
var grid = $("#mygrid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            scrollable: true,
           
            filterable: {
                extra: true,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        startswith: "Starts with",
                        eq: "Is equal to",
                        neq: "Is not equal to",
                        contains: "Contains"
                    },

                    date: {
                        eq: "Is equal to",
                        neq: "Is not equal to",
                        gte: "Is after or equal to",
                        gt: "Is after",
                        lte: "Is before or equal to",
                        lt: "Is before",
                    }

                }
            },
```

When I say extra: true, it is applying to all columns. But I don't want to display extra filter for string type column. How can I enable extra:true for only date column?

Answer (score 1):

You might define `extra` in `Columns.filterable` as well.

Example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    filterable: {
        extra: false
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "age", filterable: { extra: true} }
    ]  
});
```

This defines that by default it should use `extra` as `false` **but** for `age` column it is going to be `true`.

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/fyje2c1g/

Comment: Hi OnaBai thanks for your reply.. I've tested your code and it is working as I expected when we dont have column menu. But when I enable the column menu, it is failing. Is there any other way to do this? Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/42ef38mu/2/

Comment: :( hhmmm is there any way to handle this?

Comment: No, as far as I know :-(